# Apps Script - Update the user on code execution status

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Some of the scripts that I run take a long time and users might get concerned that a script stopped working if they can't see the status/step. I have added a spinner to the `Sidebar` to at least indicate that the script started running, but I would like to do more than that.

Ideally, I would be able to directly update the `Sidebar` contents from the `GAS`, but I gather than is not possible because of sandboxing. I have seen other questions and answers that discuss using success handlers in a daisy chain like this:

```
function uploadActivities(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).activities_upload();
}
function onSuccess(lastStatus){
  $('#codestatus').text(lastStatus);
  google.script.run.step_two();
}
```

It is a hack and it would require me to split the code into smaller steps and pass values to the UI, which don't belong in the UI, and back to the code. I really don't like that approach and maintenance could be a bear.

I have tried creating a `var` in `GAS` and updating that value as the code progresses. However, I can't find a way to get the UI to periodically check until the code execution is complete AND to successfully update the UI after each step.

Here is the code I have created:

```
function uploadActivities(){
  google.script.run.activities_upload();
  getStatus();
}
function getStatus(){
  var isActive = true;
  while(isActive){
    var lastStatus = google.script.run.getStatus();
    $('#codestatus').text(lastStatus);
    if(lastStatus === 'Complete'){ isActive = false; }
  }
}
```

In `GAS` I use this code:

```
var codeStatus = 'start';

function getStatus(){
  return codeStatus;    
}

function activities_upload(){
  codeStatus = 'Started Execution';
  ...
  codeStatus = 'Extracting Values';
  ...
  codeStatus = 'Uploading Activities';
  ...
  codeStatus = 'Complete';
}
```

It runs the required code, and even updates the `#codestatus` `div` with the first value, but it doesn't get any values beyond the first value. Additionally, it creates a continuous loop if there is an error in the code execution, so that isn't good either.

Is there a good, efficient, and safe way to complete this approach? Or, is there a better way to notify the user of the code execution status so they don't get worried if it takes a while, and can tell if there has been an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have struggled with this for some time. Unfortunately, I don't have a good fix for your approach, but I can show what I finally did and it seems to be working.

First, create an easy way to send a `toast` to your users.

```
function updateStatus_(alert,title){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var title_ = title!=""?title:"";
  ui.toast(alert,title_);
}
```

Second, as required, use the toast to update the user.

```
function activities_upload(){
  updateStatus_('Started Execution');
  ...
  updateStatus_('Extracting Values');
  ...
  updateStatus_('Uploading Activities');
  ...
  updateStatus_('Complete');
}
```

This will alert the user with a temporary message as the code progresses and not require the user to clear an alert.

Please note that if the steps progress rapidly the user will see the `toast` flash on the screen only to be quickly replaced by the next `toast`. So, make sure you don't have too many throughout your execution.